# How does Gecko (or any other layout engine) render a document/page?

Tags: algorithm, browser, gecko

It was kind of hard to go through Gecko's documentation to see how it renders a web page.

I'm doing some performance analysis for my projects across the leading browsers to see how to improve response time. I am aware of optimization techniques out there but I don't really understand their basis — which I believe would be resolved if I knew how browser engines do their thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[I gave a tech talk](http://in.youtube.com/watch?v=a2_6bGNZ7bA) on material that might be useful a few years ago.  It wasn't the best of presentations, but I think I did manage to convey some useful information despite that. (Slides at http://dbaron.org/talks/2008-11-12-faster-html-and-css/slide-1.xhtml or http://dbaron.org/talks/2008-11-12-faster-html-and-css/master.xhtml.)

Comment: David,

Watching at least the first 15mins of it already answered some of my questions.

Thank you very much.